# Multiple OR for one variable and with AND CONDITION

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, conditional, if, operators

How to write this code
If @br !=  'X' OR 'Y' OR 'Z' AND @PROF=='N'

Answer (score 4):

This question is honestly pretty bad and likely should be closed due to lack of details/efforts displayed, but as its a fairly simple answer, I thought I would put something up for those that face the same issue.

You would want to write this utilizing parenthesis to group together the nested logic statements.

So This would be what you want:

```ampscript
IF (@BR != 'X' OR @BR != 'Y' OR @BR != 'Z') AND @PROF == 'N' THEN
```

Or if you want to get fancy, you can fake an 'INCLUDES' in AMPscript using IndexOf, like below and limit it to just the two logic statements/conditionals.

```ampscript
IF INDEXOF("|X|Y|Z|",CONCAT("|",@BR,"|")) < 1 AND @PROF = 'N'
```

This will compare your @BR var (using the bars to help contain it to do a hard match and not a soft match) to the string with your specific excluded values (again use bars on either side to force a hard match). Meaning it will return 1+ if BR value is in that string, negating the condition.